# Calculate 2 columns together in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Thanks to some nice people from StackOverflow I got my Insert data to MySQL data to work. I have the following columns in my database:

```
P_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Date DATE NOT NULL,
Name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
Address VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
Day_hours INT NOT NULL,
Day_minutes INT NOT NULL,
Km_to_address INT NOT NULL,
Time_to_address INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(P_id)
```

When I add my data to the database, it goes through my servlet here:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", ""); 
            String sql = "INSERT INTO Workdata (Date, Name, Address, Day_hours, Day_minutes, Km_to_address, Time_to_address) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"; 
            PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1, Date);
            pst.setString(2, Name);
            pst.setString(3, Address);
            pst.setString(4, Day_hours);
            pst.setString(5, Day_minutes);
            pst.setString(6, Km_to_address);
            pst.setString(7,  Time_to_address);
```

My meaning of this is that I am making a JQuery calendar system, where I can choose a "from" date and "to" date. That time interval should return all the hours that I have been worked. So fx this is work from 1 day:

```
                Allday_hours            Allday_minutes
job 1:             2                         45
Job 2:             3                         30
Job 3:             1                         45
Job 4:             4                         15
```

When these hours and minutes is calculated it is 11.35 hours. So now comes my question. How can I calculate this? If I take the sum of the hours only it is 10. When I take the sum of Allday_minutes it is 135 minutes. That means that the 135 minutes has to be change to 1.35 hours and added to the Allday_hours. Therefore the result would be: 11.35 hours. But I don't know how to do this?

First of I made a column in the database, that was named Allday_hours, where it got calculated. Here I used the query below to calculate. But I can understand that this is not a good idea.

```
SELECT *, (Day_hours + (Day_minutes / 100)) as Allday_hours FROM Workdata
```

If you choose from 1 janurary to 1 marts. Then I need a query that runs through all the Day_hours and take the sum. After that run through Allday_minutes and convert them to hours. Afterwords the SUM of Allday_hours and Allday_minutes together.
So does anyone know how I can do this, without making a fictional column
Best regards
Mads

Comment: I don't understand the arithmetic. :-(

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. I have tried to edit my description. Maybe It is more clear now?

Comment: On my planet (Earth) 1 hour = 60 minutes. How many minutes are there in 1 hour on your planet? Ah unless "minutes" aren't really "minutes" at all, but actually (decimal) fractions of an hour!!!

Comment: If you choose from 1 janurary to 1 marts. Then I need a query that runs through all the Day_hours and take the sum. After that run through Allday_minutes and convert them to hours. Afterwords the SUM of Allday_hours and Allday_minutes together

Comment: You're weren't making a whole lot of sense at the beginning. It's not getting better. 1 "minute" does not normally equal 1/100th of an hour.

Comment: Hey I am asking here because I don't know how to make the query. If I wasn't a beginner, I wouldn't ask here.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just store the hours and minutes together in a `TIME` type column and then do something like

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(day_time))) FROM workdata WHERE blabla
```

?

Comment: Hello. Thanks a lot for your answer. Somebody said on Stackoverflow, that it would be a very bad idea to make an extra column to take the sum day for day. That means have a fictional column.

Comment: I mean that when you submit the time you worked in a day, you should store hours and minutes together in only one column (TIME format) instead of two for hours and minutes. Then for calculating the time spent each day you just have to sum this column (using my query) where day = blabla (I assume that you have another column in your table for the day date ?)

Comment: ah ok sorry. I now what you mean now I think. So fx if I worked 2.45 hours at one place, I could put 2.35 in my HTML form? I mean I don't have to convert everything to minutes right, when I put it in my HTML form?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand how you choose the "from" and "to" dates you worked in a day. What I imagine is that in your html you have a JS picker to select the hour/minute you start working and anotcher picker for the end. After submit you have 2 times. Now, you just have to store the interval in your table as I said in my comments and answer. For a given day you have multiple rows with directly the times spent for a job. You use my query (sum all the times where day = day_you_want) and then you're done : you have the number of hours (in a time format) you spent this day.

Comment: And you don't have to calculate the total number of hours by summing the hours and then converting the minutes in hours like sum(hours) + sum(minutes/60) (at the end the number of minutes is equal to mod(minutes,60).

Answer (score 0):

Convert everything to minutes.
Then divide sum with 60 and truncate decimal places for hours,
and MOD sum with 60 for minutes.

SELECT 
  TRUNCATE(((SUM(Day_hours)*60 + SUM(Day_minutes))/60),0) AS hours,
  MOD((SUM(Day_hours)*60 + SUM(Day_minutes)),60) AS minutes
FROM Workdata